# What permissions are required to link Azure Boards Teams app to project?

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-boards

I am the project administrator.
I have installed the Azure Boards App.
I have signed in with my work login to the Azure Boards app in Teams.

When I try to link my project to a Teams channel, I get the following error:

"You are not authorized to access one or more resources required to complete this action."

Not sure what additional permissions other than "Admin" I could need.

Comment: On-premise or hosted?

Answer (score 5):

You can try another thing, that could be helptfull
On the Azure Boards -> Organization Settings --> Permissions
Turn on two itens painted in yellow

[image]

Comment: Enabling the first one (Third party app access with OAuth), for enough for me. No need to Turn On (Allow public project). Thanks

Comment: Just found the official MSTR doc, they mention (Third party app access with OAth) should be sufficient: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops#sorry-something-went-wrong-please-try-again

Answer (score 0):

I´ve got the same error last month.
Please, check if ALL of Microsoft Teams members are administrators on Azure Boards project before to try to login Azure Board app in Teams.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and have archived the channel and created a new Teams channel with reauthentication.

That sorts the issue.